# Why does my javaFX field reset in every keyframe?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to write a simple snake game using javaFX, and I'm currently working on the movement. I'm using a timeline to make the snake move every keyframe, and then register keyEvents to change directions. But everytime I change directions, the field instantly goes back to its initial value. I know my code is rough and messy, this is my first time properly working with javaFX. I also know that I should be segmenting my code more, but I really just want to get this part working.
The issue is probably big and obvious, but I'm new and stupid, anybody know what's wrong? Thank you!

MAIN CODE:

```
public class Main2 extends Application {
    @FXML
    private Direction dir;
    
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        try {
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Snake");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(290,190,10,10);
            rec.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            root.getChildren().add(rec);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();  
            root.requestFocus();
            dir = Direction.RIGHT;
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.1),e->{
                
                System.out.println(dir);
                


            }));
            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();
            
            
        } catch (Exception IOException) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        
    }

    

    public void setDirection(Direction d){
        switch (d){
            case UP:
                dir = Direction.UP;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                dir = Direction.DOWN;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                dir = Direction.LEFT;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                dir = Direction.RIGHT;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }


    }

    @FXML
    void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT:
                        setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
                        System.out.println(this.dir);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
                        System.out.println(this.dir);
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
                        System.out.println(this.dir);
                        break;
                    case UP:
                        setDirection(Direction.UP);
                        System.out.println(this.dir);
                        break;
                    default:                        
                        break;


                }
    }


    

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Main2">
   <children>
      <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="380.0" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="10.0" width="582.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: The main issue with your code is that you're using your `Application` class as an FXML controller. The JavaFX framework creates an instance of that class for you upon startup; it's that instance whose `start` method is invoked. But the `FXMLLoader`, by default, is creating *another* instance, and it's _that_ instance that is linked with the FXML file. Your timeline is seeing the field of the first instance, not the second instance. Create a separate class to function as your FXML controller.

Comment: As an aside, the implementation of `setDirection` can just be `this.dir = d;`. Also, you are not defining the `dir` instance in the FXML file, so there is no need for that field to be annotated with `@FXML` (doing so hurts readability).

Comment: *"I also know that I should be segmenting my code more, but I really just want to get this part working."* -> and yet, as noted out by Slaw, not segmenting your code caused you to create errors and waste more time than you would have done had you done what you already knew you needed to do.  But I'm sure you understand that now, sometimes things are clearer in hindsight and sometimes we learn through our mistakes.